# How to join two XML tables and nest it without repeating

Tags: c#, xml, linq, join, nested

I am trying to join two XML files below

***XML File 1 - Journals***

```
<Journals>
    <JournalID>1</JournalID>
    <Description>BKI- 1</Description>
</Journals>
<Journals>
    <JournalID>2</JournalID>
    <Description>BKI- 2</Description>
</Journals>
```

***XML File 2 - TRANSACTION***

```
<Transaction>
    <JID>1</JID>
    <TransactionID>0005932053</TransactionID>
    <Period>5</Period>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <JID>1</JID>
    <TransactionID>0005932054</TransactionID>
    <Period>8</Period>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <JID>2</JID>
    <TransactionID>0005932053</TransactionID>
    <Period>2</Period>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <JID>2</JID>
    <TransactionID>0005932053</TransactionID>
    <Period>4</Period>
</Transaction>
```

into one that would be as below

***XML OUTPUT***

```
<Journals>
    <JournalID>1</JournalID>
    <Description>BKI- 1</Description>
        <Transaction>
            <JID>1</JID>
            <TransactionID>0005932053</TransactionID>
            <Period>5</Period>
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
            <JID>1</JID>
            <TransactionID>0005932054</TransactionID>
            <Period>8</Period>
        </Transaction>
</Journals>
<Journals>
    <JournalID>2</JournalID>
    <Description>BKI- 2</Description>
        <Transaction>
            <JID>2</JID>
            <TransactionID>0005932053</TransactionID>
            <Period>2</Period>
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
            <JID>2</JID>
            <TransactionID>0005932053</TransactionID>
            <Period>4</Period>
        </Transaction>

</Journals>
```

As you can see I am trying to get a join it so that for Each Journal - all transactions would be displayed as child nodes.

My code so far - fails to do this(as it replicates Journals node for each transaction) :

> ```
>         XDocument FileTransactions = XDocument.Load("Final_Transaction.xml");
>         XDocument FileJournals = XDocument.Load("Final_Journals.xml");
>         var joinQuery = from j in FileJournals.Root.Descendants("Final_Journals")
>
>                         join t in FileTransactions.Root.Descendants("Final_Transaction")
>
>                         on (string)j.Element("JournalID").Value equals (string)t.Element("JID").Value
>
>                         select new XElement("Journals",
>         new XElement("JournalID", (string)j.Element("JournalID")),
>         new XElement("Description", (string)j.Element("Description")),
>         new XElement("Type", (string)j.Element("Type")),
>         new XElement("Transaction", new XElement(t))
>                 );
> ```

Do I need to add a foreach loop in here ? how can i scaffold out all relevant child nodes within my parent node without repeating the Parent Node ?

I have tried looking at tutorials and other posts - none of them cover the complexity I am facing

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: I would loop through the transactions file and save all individual transactions to a dictionary where the key is the `JID` and the value a list of transactions. Then I'd loop through the journals file and inject the corresponding transactions (via `JournalID`) by using the `Add` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with for loops or join (with for loops).  I used join.  You need to use well formed xml so I added a root tag to the inputs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string journalsStr = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string transactionsStr = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // xml files are not well formed. A well formed xml has only one root tag
            string jXml = File.ReadAllText(journalsStr);
            jXml = string.Format("<Root>{0}</Root>", jXml);
            XDocument jDoc = XDocument.Parse(jXml);
            string tXml = File.ReadAllText(transactionsStr);
            tXml = string.Format("<Root>{0}</Root>", tXml);
            XDocument tDoc = XDocument.Parse(tXml);

            var query = (from j in jDoc.Descendants("Journals")
                          join t in tDoc.Descendants("Transaction") on (int)j.Element("JournalID") equals (int)t.Element("JID")
                         select new {j = j, t = t}
                         ).ToList();

            var groups = query.GroupBy(x => (int)x.j.Element("JournalID")).ToList();

            string root = "<Journals></Journals>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(root);
            XElement journals = doc.Root;
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                XElement journal = group.First().j;
                foreach (var trans in group)
                {
                    journal.Add(trans.t);
                }
                journals.Add(journal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: jdweng , thank you so much for this - indeed this is exactly what i needed. I am a little surprised that there are no tutorials online to address this kind of issue... But You have made my day with your solution. You are a star !